# How to inject NestJS config into TypeORM entity?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-config

Let's have simplified TypeORM entity `User`:

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseDatabaseEntity {
  @Column({
    length: 255,
  })
  public firstName!: string;

  @Column({ length: 60 })
  @Exclude()
  public password: string;

  @BeforeUpdate()
  @BeforeInsert()
  private hashPassword(): void {
    const tmpPassword = hashSync(
      this.password + 'config.auth.password.secret',
      genSaltSync(),
    );
    this.password = tmpPassword;
  }
}

}
```

I need to replace `config.auth.password.secret` with NestJS's config (namespace from ConfigService):

```
export default registerAs('app', () => {
   return {
    password: {
      secret: process.env.AUTH_PASSWORD_SECRET,
    }
  };
});
```

, but entities are not part of NestJS structure so I cannot just inject it as usual.

How to achieve NestJS configs in TypeORM entities?

Answer (score 2):

I needed this too and came up with workaround. You can't inject the config to Entity, as was said already.

I came up with solution to export object with config values that I need in Entities:

Initialize Config in app module:

```
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [defaultConfig]
    }),
// .....other imports
  ]
```

`defaultConfig` is a function gathering and checking config values. On top of that it sets values to `STATIC_CONFIG` object.

```
export const STATIC_CONFIG = {
  WEB_APP_URL: '',
  BASE_URL: '',
};

export const defaultConfig = () => {
  const port = +(process.env[ENV_SERVER.PORT] || 3000);
  const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
  const retVal = {
    PRODUCTION: production,
    PORT: port,
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000',
    URL_PREFIX: process.env.URL_PREFIX || 'http://localhost:3000',
//    ..... plenty of other values
  }

  if (retVal[ENV_S3.HOST] && !(retVal[ENV_S3.ACCESS] && retVal[ENV_S3.SECRET])) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.error('S3 configuration error: no access or secret set; exiting');
    process.exit(1);
  }

  STATIC_CONFIG.WEB_APP_URL = retVal.WEB_APP_URL;
  STATIC_CONFIG.BASE_URL = retVal.BASE_URL;

  return retVal;
};
```

And finally in my entities I use the `STATIC_CONFIG` object, for example:

```
  @Expose({ name: 'image', toPlainOnly: true, groups: [TG_MOBILE] })
  get mobileAppImage() {
    return this.id ? `${STATIC_CONFIG.BASE_URL}/static/image/${this.id}` : undefined;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Entities are not a part of the injectable providers in NestJS so inherently this isn't possible. You can make it a part of your service code, however, and do the password hashing there before insert/update.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I wanted to do, but I am not sure how to make entities part of NestJS. Can you provide example?

Comment: You can't. That's what I said. Entities are not `@Injectable()` and there's no plan to make them. Instead, you should move the hasing logic to your service. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60119494/9576186) explains a bit more in depth as to why

Comment: So I am supposed to completely remove methods from entities or make them like so: `hashPassword(generator: IUserPassGenerator)`?

Comment: If you need access to a service that should be injected, either you'll need to make the logic in a service that uses the entity, or inject the needed service into the service that makes use of the entity and pass the needed service to the entity's method. Personally, I'd go with the former rather than  the latter

Comment: @JayMcDoniel  but if i need to @Column({ type: DataType.ENUM(config.get('app.i18n.languages')) }) lang: string . What is this configuration for if it cannot be used. I not see that in other frameworks before.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel why not work if 
const config = new ConfigService({
  ignoreEnvFile: true,
  isGlobal: true,
  load: [configuration]
})

Comment: @JayMcDoniel  may be that will work in netity var c = ConfigModule.forRoot({
      ignoreEnvFile: true,
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [configuration]
    }),

Answer (score -1):

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseDatabaseEntity {
  @Column({
    length: 255,
  })
  public firstName!: string;

  @Column({
    length: 60,
    transformer: new PasswordTransformer(new ConfigService())
  })
  @Exclude()
  public password: string;
}
```

```
export class PasswordTransformer implements ValueTransformer {
  constructor(private config: ConfigService) {}

  from(value: string): string {
    return value;
  }

  to(value: string): string {
    return hashSync(
      this.password + this.config.get('AUTH_PASSWORD_SECRET'),
      genSaltSync(),
    );
  }
}
```